# What is the type of pointer to pointer?

Tags: c++

This may be a little odd, but I can't find a reasonable answer to what is the type of pointer to pointer, like for example `char**`?

Keeping in mind that pointer is not a type.

Comment: double pointer I guess.

Comment: pointer to pointer is a pointer to a pointer. I don't think my tautology is helping here. :D
On a serious note, what part of an explanation do you find unreasonable?

Comment: Pointer *is* a type.

Comment: Its type is a pointer to a pointer to a char. Try passing the wrong type to a function for example and you will be told the same by the compiler.

Comment: I normally see `char*` referred to as "pointer to char", so a `char**` would be a "pointer to pointer to char". I'm fairly sure that a pointer is a type, by any reasonable definition of "type".

Comment: @101010 double pointer? Do you mean pointer to `double`??? ;)

Comment: `char**` is the type name, somebody call it "pointer to pointer to char" other call it "char pointer pointer".

Comment: And some call it "legacy code"

Comment: @PaoloM No I mean pointer to pointer that points to an address :P

Answer (score 5):

> Keeping in mid that pointer is not a type.

Well, pointer *is* a type in the sense that it is a category of types. But indeed, the word *pointer* does not specify any specific type. Likewise, pointer to pointer is not a type. Pointer to pointer to `char` on the other hand is a type.

Consider following proposition, which is true: "(Pointer to type) is a type". Notice how the proposition is recursive. Because "Pointer to type is" a "type", you can substitute "type" with "Pointer to type" and end up with following proposition which is also true: "(Pointer to (Pointer to type)) is a type".

So, as I said, `char**` is a type. It is in the category of pointer types. An object of type `char**` points to an object of type `char*` which is also a pointer type. `char*` points to an object of type `char` which is not a pointer type.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the computer RAM as of the large warehouse with a lot of boxes. When you define a new variable and set its value, like this:

```
char c = 'A';
```

you create a new box placed somewhere in the memory (say, at the address 0x12345678). Its length equals length of `char` datatype (1 byte) and its value is set to `'A'`.
After that you can create a new variable which is a pointer to `c`:

```
char* pointer_to_c = &c;
```

Here you create a new box placed somewhere else in the memory (say, at the address 0x1234567C). Its length equals length of `char*` datatype (4 bytes on 32-bit system) and its value is set to the addess of `c` (`0x12345678`).
After that you can create a new variable which is a pointer to `pointer_to_c`:

```
char** pointer_to__pointer_to_c = &pointer_to_c;
```

Here you create a new box placed somewhere else in the memory (say, at the address 0x12345680). Its length equals length of `char**` datatype (4 bytes on 32-bit system) and its value is set to the addess of `pointer_to_c` (`0x1234567C`).

You can view the address stored in pointer variable in debug watches window or print it to console or file, like this:

```
cout << std::hex << pointer_to_c << endl;
```

So, pointer to a pointer is a variable which stores address of place in the memory where the pointer is stored.
Hope it will help